# How to filter on column name in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZaX6.png)

I want to add filter on each column like Excel filter. I already researched all solution but not find any good way.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work without knowing what any of your data or setup looks like.

1. In the Query editor, go to the Transform tab. Use **First Row as
   Headers**.
2. Select the column that you'd like to and make sure to unpivot any
   columns associated.
3. Rename the columns ( if necessary )
4. Close and Apply.

If you provide a some additional detail on the data, how it's currently configured, etc. I think it would make it easier to help.